# How do I stop Play Store connecting to a specific WiFi SSID?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi

The WiFi network at an office I frequently visit has firewalled the Play Store, or some port that the Play Store uses. In any case, it is impossible to connect to the Play Store over that network, and this has been confirmed with IT. The error message I get if I try, is "background data must be enabled" -- which it is.

This would be much less irritating if the error message weren't persistent. That's to say that if I once try to update anything while in that office, the error message comes up -- and I then can't connect to the Play Store at all from anywhere until I scrub the cache and data from the app, even though background data most certainly is enabled. Obviously this is a bug in the Play Store software: a flag is getting set and then not tested again and unset. But my question is how do I work around it.

Is there a way to tell the Play Store -- and only the Play Store, not other apps -- not to connect to a specific WiFi network?